# What is the reason of unsuccessful matrix multiplication using cublasSgemm in this code?

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, cublas

I am trying to write a simple example of matrix multiplication using cuBLAS function cublasSgemm. My code is shown below:

```
int  m =100, n = 100;
float * bold1 = new float [m*n];
float * bold2 = new float [m*n];
float * bold3 = new float [m*n];
for (int i = 0; i< m; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j <n;j++)
                {
                        bold1[i*n+j]=rand()%10;
                        bold2[i*n+j]=rand()%10;
                }

cudaError_t cudaStat;
cublasStatus_t stat;
cublasHandle_t handle;

const float alpha = 1.0;
const float beta = 0;

float * dev_bold1, * dev_bold2, *dev_bold3;
cudaStat = cudaMalloc ((void**)&bold1, sizeof(float)*m*n);
if(cudaStat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
        cout<<"problem1";
        return cudaStat;
        }
cudaStat = cudaMalloc ((void**)&bold2,sizeof(float)*m*n);
if(cudaStat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
        cout<<"problem2";
        return cudaStat;
        }

cudaStat = cudaMalloc ((void**)&bold3,sizeof(float)*m*n);
if(cudaStat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
        cout<<"problem3";
        return cudaStat;
        }

cublasSetMatrix(m,n,sizeof(float),bold1,m,dev_bold1,m);
cublasSetMatrix(m,n,sizeof(float),bold2,m,dev_bold2,m);

stat = cublasCreate(&handle);
if(stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
        cout<<"problem4";
        return stat;
        }
cout<<stat<<"     "<<CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS<<"\n";
stat = cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, m, m, n ,&alpha, dev_bold1, n, dev_bold2, n, &beta,dev_bold3,m);

if (stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
        cout<<"problem5";
        return stat;
        }
cudaStat = cudaMemcpy(bold3,dev_bold3,sizeof(float)*m*n,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
if (cudaStat != cudaSuccess)
        {
        cout<<"problem6";
        return cudaStat;
        }

delete []bold1;
delete []bold2;
cudaFree(dev_bold1);
cudaFree(dev_bold2);
cudaFree(dev_bold3);
```

In this code, I want to multiply to matrices bold1 and bold2 which are filled with random numbers.
The code return "problem 5" which is related to this part of code:

```
stat = cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, m, m, n ,&alpha, dev_bold1, n, dev_bold2, n, &beta,dev_bold3,m);

    if (stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
            {
            cout<<"problem5";
            return stat;
            }
```

I also print stat and it shows "13"!

Can anybody please help me to understand what is the problem with my code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main mistake is in your `cudaMalloc` statements, you are allocating the wrong pointer:

```
float * dev_bold1, * dev_bold2, *dev_bold3;
cudaStat = cudaMalloc ((void**)&bold1, sizeof(float)*m*n);
                                ^
                                |
                             this should be dev_bold1
```

and likewise for the other 2 `cudaMalloc` statements.

The following code has those errors fixed, and returns no runtime errors:

```
$ cat t1235.cu

#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int  m =100, n = 100;
float * bold1 = new float [m*n];
float * bold2 = new float [m*n];
float * bold3 = new float [m*n];
for (int i = 0; i< m; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j <n;j++)
                {
                        bold1[i*n+j]=rand()%10;
                        bold2[i*n+j]=rand()%10;
                }

cudaError_t cudaStat;
cublasStatus_t stat;
cublasHandle_t handle;

const float alpha = 1.0;
const float beta = 0;

float * dev_bold1, * dev_bold2, *dev_bold3;
cudaStat = cudaMalloc ((void**)&dev_bold1, sizeof(float)*m*n);
if(cudaStat != cudaSuccess)
        {
        cout<<"problem1";
        return cudaStat;
        }
cudaStat = cudaMalloc ((void**)&dev_bold2,sizeof(float)*m*n);
if(cudaStat != cudaSuccess)
        {
        cout<<"problem2";
        return cudaStat;
        }

cudaStat = cudaMalloc ((void**)&dev_bold3,sizeof(float)*m*n);
if(cudaStat != cudaSuccess)
        {
        cout<<"problem3";
        return cudaStat;
        }

cublasSetMatrix(m,n,sizeof(float),bold1,m,dev_bold1,m);
cublasSetMatrix(m,n,sizeof(float),bold2,m,dev_bold2,m);

stat = cublasCreate(&handle);
if(stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
        cout<<"problem4";
        return stat;
        }
cout<<stat<<"     "<<CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS<<"\n";
stat = cublasSgemm(handle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, m, m, n ,&alpha, dev_bold1, n, dev_bold2, n, &beta,dev_bold3,m);

if (stat != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
        {
        cout<<"problem5";
        return stat;
        }
cudaStat = cudaMemcpy(bold3,dev_bold3,sizeof(float)*m*n,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
if (cudaStat != cudaSuccess)
        {
        cout<<"problem6";
        return cudaStat;
        }

delete []bold1;
delete []bold2;
cudaFree(dev_bold1);
cudaFree(dev_bold2);
cudaFree(dev_bold3);

return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1235 t1235.cu -lcublas
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1235
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
0     0
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

I also changed a few of your error checking statements where you were checking cuda error return values against cublas error types.